# navigationItem not displayed when VC called with self.present

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

need an help on this as I am struggling for few days now...

I have a VC with a Navigation Item called from viewDiDLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.customization()
    self.fetchData()
}
```

...

```
func customization() {
        self.navigationItem.title = self.currentUser?.displayName
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    let icon = UIImage.init(named: "back")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: icon!, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissSelf))
    backButton.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.0157, green: 0.498, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    print("called customization()")
}
```

This works flawlessy with no issues when called with triggered segue Show.

When I call the VC with the below :

```
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I got the method to reach viewDidLoad and customizations(), from the console:

```
called customization()
```

but navigationItem is not displaying.

Tried to copy the methods in customization() from the calling method, they are executed but no show as well.

Any idea what's wrong here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add navigation when presenting:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thant works. Can you please add a brief explanation why that is necessary as in other VC I have that was not necessary. Thanks!

Comment: When you are going to push the view controller then you need navigation controller to push the VC. so Navigation auto embeds with push. And when we are going to present view controller then we have to present it with self(controller), not navigation controller so we need to embed this navigation controller into presented VC.
  
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html

Comment: Perfect! thanks. Now last thing. If I try to close the SecondVC called with your code it does nothing. To close it I use: navController.popViewController(animated: true) . If I use self.dismiss instead it crashes, any idea?

Comment: You have to dismiss the viewcontroller like: self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Pop will work with push and dismiss will work with present